# How do I get value from x:name from xaml in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

As my question, I would like to get value from x:name programmaticaly in c#...
I'm working in metro apps using c# / xaml..

```
    <Border x:Name="border1"  BorderBrush="Black">
        <Image Width="95" Height="95" />
    </Border>
```

Are there any way to get "border1" in c#?

Comment: what do you want that for??

Comment: There should be a class member called border1 in your partial class that you can use directly.